# How do I change the appearance of my banner?

Tags: diablo-iii

I keep unlocking new banner sigils/shapes/accents by completing various achievements, but how do I actually use them? My banner (<kbd>G</kbd> key) doesn't actually seem to change its appearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to click on the banner behind your hero on the main menu.

[image]
(Geez, the starting Wizard armor makes her look like a tramp...)

Answer (score 2):

Click on the banner either on the start screen shown, or in town. It will open up the banner with the modification panel on the left. You can change shape, sigil position, banner color, pattern and sigil color using "dye" (bottom button). When you are done, click save. Your changes will appear.